# How to check if a module is enabled or not inside a block in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have a block in an XML file, and I want to hide it if a specific module doesn't enable (for example Mymodule2), how can I do it please, is there an attribute should I add it or not

```
<block ifconfig="zendesk/ticket/backend/order_view"
                       class="Vendor\Mymodule\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Info"
                       name="some_name"
                       aclResource="Vendor_Mymodule:myresource"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code.

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" ifconfig="contact/contact/enabled" name="contact-us-link"/>
```

You need to add ***ifconfig*** and path of the extension enabled so it will work for you.

Happy Coding.